# Java - Map<String, Integer> converted to Object[], how to sort

Tags: java

I have finally gotten my code to where it works. Although it isnt the easiest to read. 
I am reading from a text file that has

```
Date/time Tip from xxx
tip    totalAmount
```

My code now takes the amount tipped by a person and adds them together. eg X tip 10, X tip 20, X tip 30, Y tip 200, Z tip 30, Z tip 40 and outputs

```
X=60
Y=200
Z=70
```

I did this by turning my Map< String,Integer> into an Object[] tipsPerPerson

So how would I go about sorting this Object[] tipsPerPerson into something a bit easier to read (theres over 2000 names) a bit like this

```
Y=200
Z=70
X=60
```

Here is a portion of the code that im stuck at

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Tip {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int lineNumber = 1;
    Map<String, Integer> tipsByName = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\tips.txt";

    System.out.println("Reading text from file");

    try {
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
        String line;
        String currentTipper = null;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lineNumber % 2 != 0) {
                final String tipperName = line.substring(line.indexOf("from ") + 5);
                currentTipper = tipperName;
            } else {
                final Integer tipValue = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\t")));
                // here we store the tip in the map. If we have a record we sum, else 
                // we store as is
                tipsByName.put(currentTipper, (tipsByName.get(currentTipper) == null ? 0 : tipsByName.get(currentTipper))
                        + tipValue);
            }

            lineNumber++;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
       Object[] tipsName = tipsByName.entrySet().toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < tipsByName.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(tipsName[i]); // output the map
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line: " + e.getMessage());
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: is there a specific reason to convert to Object array? you could convert to Integer array and apply sort

Comment: So you want to sort the map by its values, in descending order?

Comment: Ascending or descending. Just so I dont have to go back and forth checking values and putting them in order

Answer (score 1):

Just dump the entries into a list and sort them using a Comparator:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> a, Map.Entry<String, Integer> b) {
        return Integer.compare(b.getValue(), a.getValue());
    }
});
```

Note that `b` is compared to `a`, rather than the other way around, to give us reverse order (largest to smallest).

All done in two lines. If you then iterate over the list, it will be in the order you wanted. Use `getKey()` and `getValue()` to print, or simply use the default `toString()` of the Entry:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : entries)
    System.out.println(entry + '\n');
```

Comment: But hey you need a full hd screen to meet the line reqirmentes of the your definition ;-)

Comment: `List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());` is a possibility for the first line if you are using 1.7.

Comment: You are absolutely amazing Bohemian!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!! I was going crazy trying to get this to work!

Comment: May I ask where you learned Java? I have been using a book but I feel as if its not teaching me too much other than basic syntax

Comment: Thank you! `<blush/>`. I learned java from a friend and have used it for about 15 years. I haven't read many books about it. I learned by doing. Learn the GOF patterns, and always look for ways to use the java JDK, especially Collections. Also learn regex - it can be so powerful and useful. Always look to learn from pros - read blogs, read the better answers here and similar forums, watch youtube videos from google devs and Josh Bloch. Lastly, try to answer questions here: You might be surprised at what you don't know when you try to answer, and how much you'll learn when you answer well.

Comment: Bohemian, I have another question if you would be able to assist in it.
The first if statement I use is because my text file has two rows per entry. The first has Date/time then tip from name. the second contains the tip amount and then the total amount gained.

I recently found a bug that would cause it to terminate. If X was to tip and then add a message there would be a third line. I reworked my code do the same thing but only look for the word "from" to know where the name is and then another if statement to look numbers for the amount tipped, and then an else if to continue on reading if

Comment: the line contained a message from that name.

IT works perfect except somehow Im losing data. Where X tipped 1990 total, calculated by hand. The code gets it at 1690. If I was to update the code to what I have now do you think there would be a way to troubleshoot it or would it be better rewriting it?

Comment: It sounds like a separate, and unrelated, question. The best thing to do is ask a new question. Be specific about the problem. Show sample input data, indicating what part is optional. Show the code that you've done (only the relevant parts) and say what it's doing and what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. Don't do that! Try this instead...

```
// Get the Entries.
java.util.Set<Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = tipsByName
    .entrySet();
// Make a SortedSet with a Custom Comparator.
SortedSet<Entry<String, Integer>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Entry<String, Integer>>(
    new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
      public int compare(
          Entry<String, Integer> o1,
          Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
          return 0;
        } else if (o1 == null) {
          return -1;
        } else if (o2 == null) {
          return 1;
        }
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(
            o2.getValue());
      }
    });
// Add the Entries to the SortedSet.
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entrySet) {
  sortedSet.add(entry);
}

// Iterate the sortedSet.
Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iter = sortedSet
    .iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(iter.next()); // print your sorted items.
}
```

Comment: Ill post the rest of my code so you can see what it is im doing

Answer (score 0):

An advice: use the map and d'ont make any array convertions.
The map class gives you all that you need.
You can iterate over the keys or over the values or over both like you do right now.

Just use the key values of your map and pass it as an argument to
Collections.sort(). This works because the returned key set is of type Collection
which can be passed to the Collections.sort() method.

Than it will be ordered in alphabetical order. 
If you want something else just pass an additonal Comparator class to the Collection.sort()
or wrap your object within a customized class which implements the 
interface Comparable.

After that you just iterate throught you keys and 
invoke map.get(key) method.

Example:

```
Iterator<String> sortedKeys = map.keySet().iteator();
for (String key :keys) {

  sysout(key: "+key+" value : "+ map.get(key));
}
```

Hope it was thge answer you needed.